# How can I fill some data of the cell of the new column that is in accord with a substring of the original data using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

There are 2 dataframes, and they have simillar data.

```
A dataframe

Index Business Address
1     Oils     Moskva, Russia
2     Foods    Tokyo, Japan
3     IT       California, USA
... etc.
```

```
B dataframe

Index Country Country Calling Codes
1     USA     +1
2     Egypt   +20
3     Russia  +7
4     Korea   +82
5     Japan   +81
... etc.
```

I will add a column named 'Country Calling Codes' to A dataframe, too.

After this, 'Country' column in B dataframe will be compared with the data of 'Address' column. If the  string of 'A.Address' includes string of 'B.Country', 'B.Country Calling Codes' will be inserted to 'A.Country Calling Codes' of compared row.

Result is:

```
Index Business Address         Country Calling Codes
1     Oils     Moskva, Russia  +7
2     Foods    Tokyo, Japan    +81
3     IT       California, USA +1
```

I don't know how to deal with the issue because I don't have much experience using pandas. I should be very grateful to you if you might help me.

Comment: There is always country after last `,` in `Address` ?

Comment: No, Lots of real cases are in address. this is just simplified data for confidential. for example: "Russia (Moskva)", "Japan - Tokyo", "USA California" could be exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) for get possible strings by `Country` column and then [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) by `Series`:

```
d = B.drop_duplicates('Country').set_index('Country')['Country Calling Codes']
s = A['Address'].str.extract(f'({"|".join(d.keys())})', expand=False)
A['Country Calling Codes'] = s.map(d)
print (A)
   Index Business          Address Country Calling Codes
0      1     Oils   Moskva, Russia                    +7
1      2    Foods     Tokyo, Japan                   +81
2      3       IT  California, USA                    +1
```

**Detail**:

```
print (A['Address'].str.extract(f'({"|".join(d.keys())})', expand=False))
0    Russia
1     Japan
2       USA
Name: Address, dtype: object
```

Comment: KeyError: 'Country Calling Codes' (1st line) occurred in my code, I think it is my code's problem. I'll check it ASAP.

Comment: @XsoluteIm - check columns names, it means there is different

Comment: I solved that (it was my mistake because of cell's order), now "Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects" error in 3rd line. I just restarted my kernels for initializing once more.

Comment: @XsoluteIm - It means duplicates in `Country` column so use ` d = B.drop_duplicates('Country').set_index('Country')['Country Calling Codes']`